# JNWSpringAnimation Framework for iOS (Compile Errors)

Tags: ios, frameworks

I followed the instructions that came with the framework at the github repository. But I got an error when I tried to compile all stemming from the NSValue+JNWAdditions files.  The example project that comes with the code is meant to run in Mac OS X and not iOS.  What am I missing here when trying to use this framework for an iOS app?  For giggles I removed the aforementioned files and was able to compile but got a runtime error, I guess not surprising.  I'm fairly new to this stuff and just want to play with animation and springs :(

GitHub repository:
https://github.com/jwilling/JNWSpringAnimation

Help!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but but I'm not working in/using any swift files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Got it. For any fellow newbs out there:  I had to import UIKit into the header file of NSValue+JNWAdditions.h. This got rid of all the "Expected a type" errors! Makes sense to me now and I have no idea why this took me so long to figure out.

Womp womp